# Python / DBUtils / Databricks

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I am new to Python and need help with Databricks.

I need to do a simple copy of file from Azure Blob to ADLS using Python.

I need the code in Python file and need to be executed from Databricks instead of notebooks.

I tried the below,

Using spark.conf.set, I set the access keys for Blob and ADLS.
I use dbutils.fs.cp to copy the files.

Its executing without any error but the file actually isn't copied to ADLS.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to move files from Azure Blob Storage to ADLS using Databricks utility command (**dbuitls.fs.cp('Source', 'Destination)**):

First, I have mounted Azure Blob Storage account with name (/mnt/chepra) and ADLS Gen2 account with name (/mnt/flightdata).

**Azure Blob Storage Mount:** (/mnt/chepra)

[image]

**Azure Data Lake Storage** (/mnt/flightdata)

[image]

Now, you can use databricks utility command to cp from Azure Blob Storage to Azure Data Lake Storage as show:

```
dbutils.fs.cp('/mnt/chepra/sales.csv', '/mnt/flightdata')
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It works for me with notebooks. I need to put these in python file and execute using databricks. Any help ?